# Wi-Fi connection lost during sleep

Tags: android, wifi, sleep

On an Android 4.1 device, I have "Keep Wi-Fi on during sleep" activated in Android's settings but when my device goes to sleep and I don't wake it up for many hours, the connection to the Wi-Fi is lost. Is this a bug?

Originally in my code I used to have the following:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
this.wifiLock = wifiManager.createWifiLock("mywifilock");
this.wifiLock.acquire();
```

but I removed this code because Android 4.1 has the feature for keeping the Wi-Fi enabled. Is there something I need to do in my app to keep the Wi-Fi connection enabled?

My code runs as a service with no activity, and I run the service periodically with an AlarmManager. I placed the above code in the onCreate to get executed when the service was restarted each time. Maybe I don't understand what the purpose of the "Keep Wi-Fi on during sleep" is used for. Why would I need a wakelock?

What is also weird is that the connection is not lost on an Android 2.3 device from the same manufacturer. Perhaps this is an Android 4.1 bug?

Answer (score 0):

I think put this code in your Activity's onResume() method, so it will wake up again when your code runs.

Comment: Actually my code is a service that gets started periodically with AlarmManager. I had the code in the onCreate method.

Comment: then if you put code in onResume() then it will not work for you?

Comment: There is no onResume in services.

Comment: ok then write this code in onStart() method or in onStartCommand() method in service.

Comment: pratik is correct. onCreate() is called only once, whereas onStartCommand is called every time the service is invoked by AlarmManager.